# Alternative for IIS Advanced Logging functionality in IIS 10

Tags: iis, x-forwarded-for, iis-advanced-logging

I am trying to configure my server to overwrite the `c-ip` value with the real user IP provided by the Load Balancer within the `X-Forwarded-For` header.
This was possible within IIS 7.0 and IIS 8.5 using the [*Advanced Logging module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging)
but the module is not supported anymore in IIS 10.

Did anyone find an alternative of the Advanced Logging module for IIS 10? or at least to overwrite the `c-ip` values within the logs?

Thanks,
Cristian

Comment: Use enhanced logging to write X-Forwarded-For to IIS log files as extra field. Then in your log processing logic, use that field instead of c-ip.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi . That's simple to achieve but the business owner need to have the Original IP inserted into the default C-IP header and not in the custom one. With Advanced Logging it was fairly straight to do that but not with Enhanced Logging.

Comment: When Microsoft no longer supports that, it is only feasible to change your own approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it has been retired. For older IIS versions check [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging).